# Reindex gets scheduled by cron but never executed

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, index

For magento 2.2.4 my cron.sh looks like this (crontab is not available in this environment):

```
#!/bin/bash

PHP_BIN=`which php7-71STABLE-CLI`;

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
BIN="$DIR/bin/magento"
INI="$DIR/php.ini"

$PHP_BIN -d max_execution_time=180 -d memory_limit=756M -c $INI $BIN cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> $DIR/var/log/magento.cron.log
$PHP_BIN -d max_execution_time=180 -d memory_limit=756M -c $INI $DIR/update/cron.php >> $DIR/var/log/update.cron.log
$PHP_BIN -d max_execution_time=180 -d memory_limit=756M -c $INI $BIN setup:cron:run >> $DIR/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

It is run every minute and produces no errors.

In the table `cron_schedule` I see all kinds of scheduled entries including `indexer_reindex_all_invalid`.

While others are properly executed the reindex never gets executed. It is stuck with status `pending`.

The cron config in backend is using the default options.

Manual `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` works fine but this should be done automatically as it is in my dev environment.

I googled and searched everywhere and ran out of options. What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: have you run `php bin/magento cron:install` in terminal ?

Comment: Like I said: crontab is not available. The crons get planned from a cpanel type web frontend. The above shell script works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution. The crons in the magento backend were configured to use a separate process which does not work on our provider's server. Once I disabled that option the indexers were flying again.

Comment: how did you change this option?

Comment: Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Cron. There each cron group has a setting called "Use Separate Process". I set those to "No".