# Magento 2: Reindex script does not work with cronjob

Tags: magento2, cron, index

Ok, true desparation here. Since the reindex via default cron simply does not want to work ([Reindex gets scheduled by cron but never executed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233294/reindex-gets-scheduled-by-cron-but-never-executed)) I decided to create a separate cron just to trigger the reindex:

```
#!/bin/bash

PHP_BIN=`which php7-71STABLE-CLI`;

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
BIN="$DIR/bin/magento"
INI="$DIR/php.ini"

$PHP_BIN -d max_execution_time=180 -d memory_limit=756M -c $INI -f $BIN indexer:reindex
```

This works fine when I start this script manually on the command line. But if scheduled via cron I get these errors:

```
Design Config Grid indexer process unknown error:
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
Category Flat Data indexer process unknown error:
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string
```

... I have no words.

Things got even worse:

In the exception.log I found this:

```
[2018-07-12 13:25:06] main.CRITICAL: URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string {"exception":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Exception\\InvalidUriException(code: 0): URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string at /www/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/Uri.php:357)"} []
[2018-07-12 13:25:06] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db274388_83.catalogrule_product__tempfccd824a' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `rp`.*, IFNULL(pp1.value, pp_default.value) AS `default_price` FROM `catalogrule_product__tempfccd824a` AS `rp`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = rp.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pp_default` ON pp_default.entity_id=e.entity_id AND (pp_default.attribute_id=77) and pp_default.store_id=0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id=rp.product_id AND product_website.website_id = rp.website_id AND product_website.website_id=1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pp1` ON pp1.entity_id=e.entity_id AND (pp1.attribute_id=77) and pp1.store_id=1 ORDER BY `rp`.`website_id` ASC, `rp`.`customer_group_id` ASC, `rp`.`product_id` ASC, `rp`.`sort_order` ASC, `rp`.`rule_id` ASC
 {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db274388_83.catalogrule_product__tempfccd824a' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `rp`.*, IFNULL(pp1.value, pp_default.value) AS `default_price` FROM `catalogrule_product__tempfccd824a` AS `rp`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = rp.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pp_default` ON pp_default.entity_id=e.entity_id AND (pp_default.attribute_id=77) and pp_default.store_id=0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id=rp.product_id AND product_website.website_id = rp.website_id AND product_website.website_id=1
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `pp1` ON pp1.entity_id=e.entity_id AND (pp1.attribute_id=77) and pp1.store_id=1 ORDER BY `rp`.`website_id` ASC, `rp`.`customer_group_id` ASC, `rp`.`product_id` ASC, `rp`.`sort_order` ASC, `rp`.`rule_id` ASC
 at /www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db274388_83.catalogrule_product__tempfccd824a' doesn't exist at /www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

Magento is complaining about missing tables (`catalogrule_product__tempfccd824a`). So I checked the database and found a whole lot of weird tables that weren't there in the first place:

```
catalogrule_product7b329f37
catalogrule_product_price94df8523
catalogrule_group_website30a92cf9
```

...while the original tables were still in place. With each run of my reindex script I got more and more of these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Am having the same/similar problem, the reindex creates all these catalogrule tables - absolute pain to delete - am clueless - have you had any success finding the problem? I have located the problem to the reindex cron job but that is it.

If I reindex all through the ssh shell () indexer:reindexhen I do not get multiple tables - exception log also shows "URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string"

Any help appreciated

T

Comment: So far no success. But it seems my issue is related to my provider's config. When I trigger the cron script manually from the provider's backend panel all is fine. The problem only occurs when it is triggered via cron itself. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I seemed to have stopped the temp tables being created. I used the Cron Job Manager plugin and in Job Configuration I disabled the catalogrule_apply_all cronjob. Not really a good answer but it works. Can also be tweaked or overridden from here: /vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/etc/crontab.xml

Comment: My original issue is resolved (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233294/reindex-gets-scheduled-by-cron-but-never-executed) so a separate index cron is obsolete for me.